# Check if ul has li with a specific text in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to check, if there is a `li` element in my `ul` which has a specific text. When I enter this here in the console, I'm receiving all `li` texts:

```
jQuery(".et-pb-contact-message.contact-error ul:nth-child(2)").has("li").text();
"Name *E-Mail-Adresse *Betreff *Nachricht *Bestätigung"
```

Now I've wrote this statement into an if block, but it's sadly not working:

```js
if (!jQuery(".et-pb-contact-message.contact-error ul:nth-child(2)").has("li").text() === 'Captcha *') {
    alert("No captcha error");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et-pb-contact-message contact-error">
  <p>Bitte fülle die folgenden Felder aus:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Name&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>E-Mail-Adresse&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Betreff&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Nachricht&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Bestätigung</li>
  </ul><ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var flag = false;
jQuery(".et-pb-contact-message.contact-error ul:nth-child(2) li").each((idx, ele) => {
  console.log(ele.innerText);
  if (!flag && ele.innerText == 'Captcha *') {
    flag = true;
  }
});
if (!flag)
  alert("No captcha error");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et-pb-contact-message contact-error">
  <p>Bitte fülle die folgenden Felder aus:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Name&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>E-Mail-Adresse&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Betreff&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Nachricht&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Bestätigung</li>
    <!--<li>Captcha&nbsp;*</li>-->
  </ul>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
jQuery(".contact-error ul:nth-child(2) li").each(function(index) {
  if ($(this).html() === 'Captcha&nbsp;*')
    console.log('founded in ' + (index + 1) + 'th error');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="et-pb-contact-message contact-error">
  <p>Bitte fülle die folgenden Felder aus:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Name&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Captcha&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Betreff&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Nachricht&nbsp;*</li>
    <li>Bestätigung</li>
  </ul>
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Captcha can be everywhere. I'm checking with :nth-child(2) the first ul in my scope. The first element is p, the next is ul because I've two uls here for other needs. So in a case of an error, all error messages are in the first ul. So your solution is not 100 % correct. Maybe you can re-think it, so I can give you a check!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!(jQuery(".et-pb-contact-message.contact-error ul:nth-child(2)").has("li").text()).split(" ").includes('Captcha *')) {
    console.log("enjoy!");
  }
```

But keep in mind that the includes method does not work in ie.

Comment: Look at jQuery.inArray()

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(".et-pb-contact-message.contact-error ul:nth-child(2) li").each(function(){
  console.log(this.innerText);
});
```

Use this code to check each and every value.